# How to update $_SESSION variable with repeated $_POST

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having difficulty updating my `$_SESSION` value every time I send a `$_POST` request to the page. My current code is :

```
   foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   foreach ($_SESSION as $key1=>$value1){
       if ($key == $key1){
           $_SESSION[$key1] = $_SESSION[$key1] + $_POST[$key];
       }
   } 
}
```

my `$_SESSION` array does not update with the subsequent `$_POST` values. How do I append to the `$_SESSION` array such that when a new `$POST` request is submitted, it will update the `$_SESSION` array if the key of `$_SESSION = key` of `$_POST` instead of replacing the values in it ?

I have confirmed that the keys of `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` are set and named correctly
Thank you so much ! been stucked for almost a day :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying, try `isset`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
           $_SESSION[$key] = $_SESSION[$key] + $_POST[$key];
       }
   }
```

**You can do:**

```
$_SESSION[$key] += $_POST[$key];
```

**Instead of:**

```
$_SESSION[$key] = $_SESSION[$key] + $_POST[$key];
```

*(If you want to shorten it up a bit)*

Comment: i'm sorry but this doesnt work. the value of $_SESSION[$key] is still replaced by the value of $_POST[$key]. I need the $_SESSION[$key] value to be updated if the key of $_SESSION and $_POST is the same.

Comment: ok update, im seeing this as working if i refresh, how do i ensure that my $_SESSION is preserved when i leave the page ? Currently i'm pressing the Back button

Comment: Well it will preserve as long as it doesn't expire or if you close out your browser, it may close, but it will stay as long as you are browsing your site. Expiration can be set by your site setting a max idle time but other than that, if in a session it will stay there and only update on a `$_POST` with same `keys`.

Comment: All three of these answers will work it looks like. They all have identical outcomes. That extra loop you did messed you up is all.

Comment: No problem! The best part is you can move on with your day! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

First, change:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   if ( isset($_SESSION[$key]) ){
       $_SESSION[$key] += $value;
   }
}
```

And add the error shown (try `var_dump($_SESSION)`)

EDIT: Also you can try `array_intersect_key($_POST, $_SESSION)` so that would show the values been intersected in both arrays (by key). So code would be:

```
$array = array_intersect_key($_POST, $_SESSION);
var_dump($array); //just to check the values

foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
   $_SESSION[$key] += $_POST[$key];
}
```

Comment: the value in $_SESSION is still being replaced instead of updated. An example of var_dump is array(9) { ["Brocolli_with_scallops"]=> int(3)

Comment: Please clarify the difference between replaced and updated... maybe with some random values

Comment: example of replaced:
$_SESSION ['a] = 2
$_POST['a] = 1
$_SESSION ['a] = 1

example of updated:
$_SESSION ['a] = 2
$_POST['a] = 1
$_SESSION ['a] = 3

Comment: replace/update/edit in some way are synonyms so maybe you refer to and added value or increased value?

Comment: i tried as per my source codes you have seen, but it still doesnt update it. The value was replaced instead

Comment: up for array_intersect_key

Comment: What you want is an increasing value please try with my last code, specially with the `$array = array_intersect_key($_POST, $_SESSION);` and add after that (just for testing) `var_dump($array);`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   if(array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION)) $_SESSION[$key] += $value;
}
```

try this.. I've eliminated the unnecessary loops to make the code readable and much easier to debug.
hope my understanding with your situation is correct

Comment: it still doesnt work, whenever i do a print_r($_SESSION) after sending a new $POST , the values is still being replaced instead of updated with the current value

Comment: did you copy and pasted my code? the operator is += not =.. please check the code